# Why does my listview have triangle mark?

Tags: android, listview

[image]

My listview has a triangle mark on the bold text. Is there anyway to remove it?

Below is the custom list view which is called when the activity is executed. This is also used for another class which has a spinner, that is why a spinner is created too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/budget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_posted"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp" /> 

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: that is spinner (combo box) there.

kindly add your custom listview item layout code.

Comment: that is because of `<Spinner ... />` code.
if that is not in use, you should probably remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

from your custom listview item layout, if it's not in use.

Otherwise, set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`